# Simple way to get a table of predicted values in SAS Using PROC REG

Tags: sas, regression

I'm trying to make a polynomial trend in SAS.  This is the code that I have right now:

```
proc reg data=work.trend_line out;
model stat = stat stat_2nd_dgre stat_3rd_dgre;
run;
```

It works to get the parameters that I need but I'm stuck on the next step.  I need to get a table of predicted values based on another table with a column of independent variables.  Essentially I need a table that looks like this (the numbers are made up):

```
Stat    Stat Trend
1       1
2       1.75
3       2.9
```

I'm new to SAS and I'm looking to see if there is a simple way to do this.  I've looked through what I think is a comprehensive list of the PROC REG's options and don't see a way to do it there.

Comment: The term is scoring a data set. There are several ways and they're documented in this blog post: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/02/19/scoring-a-regression-model-in-sas.html

Comment: @Reeza Thank you! Not knowing the term was the reason I couldn't find any information.  The article is short and very clear for anybody who may have this same question.